# Как добавить данные из json в массив JS

Tags: javascript

у меня есть API https://api.frankfurter.app/2018-01-01..2021-01-01?from=USD&to=RUB оно возвращает "rates": {
"2018-01-01": {
"RUB": 57.244
},
"2018-01-08": {
"RUB": 56.953
}, т.д}
как мне добавить дату и значение по этой дате в массив (без jquery только обычный js). Массив должен иметь вид array = [{date:дата},{value:значение}]
у меня получилось сделать только это

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()

xhr.open('GET', requestURL)
xhr.responseType = 'json'
xhr.send()

xhr.onload = () => {
    console.info(xhr.response)
    var data = xhr.response
    var main = data['rates']
}
```

раньше я работал с простыми json данными, а с такими появляются трудность

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверьте, такой ли результат вам нужен:

```js
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()

xhr.open('GET', 'https://api.frankfurter.app/2018-01-01..2021-01-01?from=USD&to=RUB')
xhr.responseType = 'json'
xhr.send()

xhr.onload = () => {
    console.info(xhr.response)
    var data = xhr.response
    var main = Object.entries(data['rates'])
      .flatMap(([key, value]) => [{ date: key }, { value: value.RUB }])
    console.info(main)
}
```

Comment: Да, все работает как нужно спасибо